# How to estimate treatment effect with overlapping treatments?

Tags: experiment-design, treatment-effect, overlapping-data

I've taken over a project with an overlapping treatment design and I'm wondering how to estimate the overall effect. The description:

Our organization sends 4 separate promotional postcards to our customers based on their point in our customer lifecycle. For example, customers become eligible for promotion 1 after spending a certain amount, promotion 2 after hitting a certain order number, promotion 3 after a certain amount of elapsed time since their first purchase, and promotion 4 after contacting one of our representatives.

Based on order histories, we can assign revenue to each of the promotions, but only roughly. For example, say promo 1 was sent to customer A on Jan. 15 and promo 2 was sent to customer A on Jan. 31. We received orders from customer A on Jan. 20 and Feb. 2, for \$25 and \$50, respectively. We would attribute \$75 to promo 1 and \$50 to promo 2. Each of the promos has its own holdout group with a 90/10 split, to which customers are assigned as they become eligible for treatment. So customer A may also be in the holdout for, say, promo 3. If that is the case and customer A had become eligible for promo 3 on Jan. 25, she would have $50 in revenue attributed as a control for promo 3.

To summarize, in our data, customer A has 3 rows: two treatment assignments for promo 1 and promo 2 and one control for promo 3, with the associated revenue of \$75, \$50 and \$50.

Is there any way to pull out an overall effect of all treatments combined? If there isn't a way to do this perfectly, is there someway to get close?